# How to change my Uber password or delete the account?

Tags: security, account-management, uber

Uber was affected by the [Cloudbleed security bug](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/cloudbleed-bug-everything-you-need-to-know/), so everyone should change their passwords or delete their accounts.

But where's the "change password" feature on their web site? It's not on the [Profile page](https://riders.uber.com/profile#). And [Google doesn't find it](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Auber.com%20%22change%20password%22), either. The Profile page says:

> Please visit the Uber app on your phone if you are unable to edit a field on this page.

but after reinstalling the app, I'm not finding it there, either. [Their help page](https://help.uber.com/h/9f5e271c-7eee-4692-b0f1-74023e33a05d) says:

> How do I update my profile?
> To update your name, email, phone number, and password:
>
> 1. Select “Settings” in the main app menu
> 2. Tap the bar that displays your profile info
> 3. Tap the information you want to change.
> 4. Make your updates and click save.

but that doesn't reveal a "change password" feature, either.

A way to delete an Uber account is also well hidden.

Comment: It looks like you can change your Uber password on the web at https://accounts.uber.com/profile

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can't directly change your password the web site or the Android app (I don't know about iOS). You can, however, request that they reset your password.

1. Log out of the web site (if you're currently logged in)
2. Instead of logging back in, click "Forgot password"
3. Follow the instructions

Answer (score 4):

You can change password on Android, but it's incredibly hidden and very poor UX given how much they pour into the other parts of the app.

1. Open the app on your device.
2. Tap the hamburger menu (3
   horizontal lines) in the upper left.
3. Tap 'Settings' to go to your
   account settings.
4. Where you see your name, number and email, tap that (it's a button!).
5. Your password is at the bottom, tap that to change your password (it's also a button!).

It's incredibly annoying that you can only do things through the mobile app and not the website where you might have easier access to password managers and whatever.

They have specific buttons for adding saved places, family or profiles, but not a simple "Edit Account" button or edit buttons/styles for the account fields like email and name. You just have to *know* to tap those to edit.

Answer (score 1):

To close the security gap, either change your password (see [@aldel's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/103556/87130)) or delete your account.

I found [WikiHow instructions](http://www.wikihow.com/Cancel-an-Uber-Account) to delete an Uber account:

> 1. Open the Uber app.
> 2. Tap ☰.
> 3. Tap Help.
> 4. Tap Account and Payment.
> 5. Tap Account Settings and Ratings.
> 6. Tap Delete my Uber Account.
> 7. Fill out the two text fields.
> 8. Tap Submit.

That sequence submits a request. (The text fields ask why you want to delete your account. A simple "Bye" sufficed to submit the form.) Then:

1. Wait a few hours for the email reply.
2. Click the temporary, personal hyperlink in the email reply.

Note: Google finds instructions on the web that try to skip the first 8 steps and go directly to a link like `https://help.uber.com/h/24010fe7-7a67-4ee5-9938-c734000b144a`. That doesn't work.